# WCF service returns "no http base address" error

Tags: wcf

I am learning WCF, and following a textbook building a simple MathService. It should be hosted as a Windows Service. The hosting is configured partially in app.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name = "MathServiceLibrary.MathService">
        </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And partially programmatically:

```
myHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MathService));

Uri address = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/MathServiceLibrary");
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
Type contract = typeof(IBasicMath);

myHost.AddServiceEndpoint(contract, binding, address);

myHost.Open();
```

After installing the service, I cannot start it:

> The HttpGetEnabled property of ServiceMetadataBehavior is set to true and the HttpGetUrl property is a relative address, but there is no http base address.  Either supply an http base address or set HttpGetUrl to an absolute address.

If I set HttpGetEnabled to false, I can install the service, but it doesn't seem to be working. I cannot add a service reference to the client, and when I try to open it in the browser, I get an error 400.

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear.  You have two options here - either set a base address, or set the `HttpGetUrl` address to a absolute address.  If you set `HttpGetEnabled` to false then you won't be able to add a service reference to the service because it won't be exposing the WSDL.

Comment: @Tim Thanks, Tim! But is it possible to set a base address programmatically?

Comment: Yes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base addresse(s) can be set by using the overload of the `ServiceHost` constructor that takes an array of base addresses - see [ServiceHost Constructor (Type, Uri[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms585489(v=vs.110).aspx).

Something like this:

```
myHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MathService), new Uri[] { new Uri("http://localhost:8080/MathServiceLibrary") });

Uri address = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/MathServiceLibrary");
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
Type contract = typeof(IBasicMath);

myHost.AddServiceEndpoint(contract, binding, address);

myHost.Open();
```

The above is not tested, but the idea is the call to `ServiceHost` sets up the service at the specified URL, and the call to `AddServiceEndpoint` exposes the service for a client to consume over `WsHttpBinding`.

Comment: Hi Tim,
Thank you for your answer. May I ask why we need duplicating the same address? Thanks again.

Comment: @DavidShochet - You're not duplicating addresses, even though it looks like it.  The call to the `ServiceHost` constructor is setting the base address, which will (by default) use `basicHttpBinding`.  The call to `AddServiceEndpoint` will add an endpoint with `wsHttpBinding`.

Comment: Sorry for the naive question, but why do I need to provide the base address that is not used, as I understand, as I don't use basicHttpBinding?

Comment: But the base address *is* used  - it's used for the `httpGetUrl`.